# Django Template Not Formatting <pre> Tag Correctly

Tags: html, json, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to display raw json data in a Django template with the `<pre>` tag.

I have this working in several places but for some reason one of my json samples is not working correctly.

To get the json I take a python dictionary with nested lists and dictionaries. I then run that through `json.dumps()` to get my json. It looks like this:

```
data = {'parent_key': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3'], 'problem_key': ['problem_data1', 'problem_data2', 'problem_data3']}

json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

With my other dictionaries this works well - The expected output is 'pretty' formatted json - ie:

```
parent_key {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2", 
    "key3": [
        "obj1",
        "obj2",
        "obj3",
        ], 
    "problem_key": "[\n    \"problem_data1\",\n    \"problem_data2\",\n    \"problem_data3\"\n    ]
```

In the Django template my code looks like so:

```
{% for k, v in json_data.items %}
    <pre>{{ k }} {{ v }}</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see most of the data formats correctly but that last section actually prints the newline characters instead of formatting them.

Any thoughts?

**Edit - Render**
Below - search_result['display'] is a normal dic

```
    search_result['display'] = json.dumps(search_result['display'], indent=4)

    return render(request, 'iocs/ioc_check.html', {'search_result': search_result, 'pp_result': pp_data, 'url_haus': url_haus_,
                                                   'envcount': envcount})
```

**Edit - Actual Output**

```
www.google.com.dns-report.com {
    "Source": "CrowdStrike-Intel",
    "Malicious_Confidence": "high",
    "First_Seen": "2019-05-07 14:10:26",
    "Last_Seen": "2019-05-15 20:31:17",
    "TISAG_SEIR": "TISAG-SEIR",
    "Malware": [
        "FakeDead"
    ],
    "Threat_Type": "Error",
    "Kill_Chain": [
        "C2"
    ],
    "Tags": [
        "domain",
        [
            "C2"
        ],
        [
            "FakeDead"
        ]
    ],
    "Additional_Context": "[\n    {\n        \"indicator\": \"4e85c248eab9eedd3941640699cb1c4b\",\n        \"type\": \"hash_md5\",\n        \"created_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\",\n        \"last_valid_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"indicator\": \"96723797870a5531abec4e99fa84548837e9022e9f22074cf99973ab7df2a2e7\",\n        \"type\": \"hash_sha256\",\n        \"created_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\",\n        \"last_valid_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"indicator\": \"ff166de7d1b17a008e5bc3f3356fbf2dbe4906ec\",\n        \"type\": \"hash_sha1\",\n        \"created_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\",\n        \"last_valid_date\": \"2019-05-07 14:10:26\"\n    }\n]"
}
```

Comment: That's normal, you should use the `|safe` template filter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm new to this, can you link to some docs?

Comment: hold on, `json_data` is a string, correct?

Comment: I believe it is

Comment: but then normally the `{% for ... %}` loop will never iterate. Can you show the **HTML** output you get?

Comment: Its in a dictionary so It can loop well -  I will post the actual output. You will see that the first half is correct and the end piece is off

Comment: but the result of a `json.dumps` is a string, so I have the impression that you did not pass the correct variable to your template.

Comment: I passed the entire dictionary to `json.dumps` in one pass, so I'm not sure why some works and some doesn't

Comment: can you show how you call `render(..)` here. I'm quite sure something goes wrong with passing the *outcome* of `json.dumps`, since a `str`ing has *no* `.items()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willem Van Onsem figured this out for me in the comments. I wanted to post the answer in case anyone else has this issue.

The reason it was printing strange is because one small section of my end result had already been converted from JSON to a string. To solve this I just pushed the entire data set back into a `json.loads()` then re-dumped it back into a `json.dumps()`  Once I did this it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The output of of [**`json.dumps`** [Pyton-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.dumps) is a `str`ing:

> (...)
>
> Serialize obj to a **JSON formatted `str`** using this conversion table. The arguments have the same meaning as in `dump()`.

If you thus want to render the outcome, you render this with a simple:

```
<pre>{{ json_data }}</pre>
```

Since it is a `str`ing, that means that it has no `.items()` as well, and hence a `{% for k, v in json_data.items %}` should result in no iteration at all. It therefore looks like you passed something else than your `json_data` object to the template.

Based on your `render(..)` call, it thus should look like:

```
<pre>{{ search_result.display }}</pre>
```

After some discussion, it looks like part of the API response is JSON formatted, so in that case it is probably best to first JSON load that part, and then make a JSON dump for the entire dictionary and render it like discussed above.

Comment: I added this change and there is no change in my display. Still not formatted right

Comment: I'll try, but the way i think it is working is I have a dic - where the key is normal and the value is the str json data. There for the only iteration is to print the value the same as you are here

Comment: @Joe: but you should print the value here, not a list, since otherwise you print the `repr(..)` of the values. This has nothing to do with Django then, but with how Python formats lists, so your JSON serialization is then omitted.

Comment: I was trying initially but I must have been doing something wrong - when I was trying to print it `{{ search_result.display }}` nothing printed - But when I looped I got the expected result - I have no idea why.

Comment: So I get the exact same result with this. First half formatted correctly but that end piece is printing `\n` chars and what not

Comment: @Joe: then it looks like you assigned something else to your `search_result['display']` later in the view, since I tested this locally, and it seems to work.

Comment: Creating this dic is the very last thing I do in the view so it can't get altered. We can see the correct formatting data there (the newline chars etc)  Just not sure why it is not being displayed like the rest of the json data

Comment: @Joe: can you print the type: `print(search_result['display'])`. Your *original* search_result['display']` does not by any chance is already partially json-dumped?

Comment: I removed the `json.dump` from the view code and that particular section is still printing with the  `\n` data and funny spacing. So maybe it is already jsonified? I'll test some more

Comment: @Joe: this looks the most plausible solution, perhaps you fetched it through an API, and thus that value is then not a list, but string that already contains a JSON dump of that list.

Comment: Its strange because all data in this dic came from the same API call. I am just pulling relevant data from the dic  - NOTE when I test this in pycharm on my local system it works correctly. Not sure why its breaking on server

Comment: @Joe: but did you use `response.json()` to fully deserialize the data?

Comment: Yes I am returning the data from the call with `response.json()`

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! For some reason that specific section of the response was getting formatted differently. I used `json.loads()` to force that particular section back to a dictionary then did `json.dumps()` on all of it and it works. If you post this I will accept the answer! Again Thank you!!!